# ¿Cómo cambiar la versión de Python que usa NVIM?

Tags: python, debian, vim

estoy usando NVIM para mis proyectos pero necesito especificamente la versión 3.7.3 para que sea ejecutada con nvim, estoy utilizando debian, si se preguntan el comando `python3 -V` en el terminal me devuelve: Python 3.7.3.. Pero cuando estoy en nvim y ejecuto el siguiente comando `:python import sys; print(sys.version)` me devuelve la versión de python 2.7.16.. Entonces, habrá una manera de que por defecto me ejecute la versión 3.7.3 en vez de la versión 2.7.16 ?

Comment: Otra cosa.. El comando `:echo has('python3')` me devuelve 1

Comment: Intentaste usando `:python3 import sys; print(sys.version)`?

Comment: @braver olvide comentar que ese comando si me devuelve la versión que quiero, pero al momento de iniciar el nvim me aparece este error `unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (3.6.0+) support.`

Comment: Segun [esto](https://github.com/deoplete-plugins/deoplete-jedi/wiki/Setting-up-Python-for-Neovim) puedes activarlo instalando el paquete de neovim con pip3 (`pip3 install --user neovim`).